# Getting users city and country info using Google GeoApi

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I am using this code to get users full address info

```
function getGeo() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (a) {
            $("#geoLoc").html("Determing your location..");
            $.post("https://mysite.com/getloc.php?l=" + a.coords.latitude + "," + a.coords.longitude, function (b) {
                var c = jsonParse(b);
                geo_adres = c.results[0].formatted_address;
                latitude = a.coords.latitude;
                longitude = a.coords.longitude;
                $("#geoLoc").html(c.results[0].formatted_address);
                $("#geoLoc").show("slow")
            })
        }, function (a) {
            alert(geolocationErrorMessages[a.code])
        }, {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            maximumAge: 12e4
        });
        return false
    } else {
        alert("Your browser doesn't support geo-location feature...")
    }
}
```

EDIT:
getloc.php contains this codes (c var in javascript)

```
$data = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=". $_GET['l'] ."&sensor=false");
print $data;
```

Actually all i want is to get users city and country info like that `city, country`

How should i change this one `c.results[0].formatted_address` to achieve that ?

Comment: i edited my question please check

Comment: you should look at the documentation for the geocoder api, [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Results). I would start by examining the contents of the array `c.results[0].address_components[]`.

Comment: @Ahmetvardar check i posted an answer, hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this working php code, i hope this is going to help you a lot :) and let mew know in case of any query --

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false");

$jsonnew =json_decode($data,true);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($jsonnew['results'][7]['address_components'][2]['long_name']);

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($jsonnew['results'][6]['address_components'][2]['long_name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need your `getloc` PHP script. The Maps Javascript API includes a [`Geocoder`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Geocoder) class.